# Create Table LINQ TO SQL

Tags: sql, linq

I want to create a table in my database with LINQ TO SQL. This is what I have:

```
public void CreateUserTab(string nick) 
{
    string sqlCdm = string.Format("CREATE TABLE Customer (Nick nvarchar(30) PRIMARY KEY, AzetID nvarchar(30), RpText nvarchar(300), Your bit, Sing nvarchar(30), Time DateTime, OriginalTxt nvarchar(300))"); 
    _dc.ExecuteCommand(sqlCdm); 
    _dc.SubmitChanges(); 
}
```

After executing this, my table does not appear in the database.

Comment: This doesn't really have anything to do with LINQ to SQL.

Answer (score 3):

You have to provide a table name as a second parameter to the `String.Format` call.

Right now the `{0}` placeholder is not replaced.